# Profile xyz does not exist aws serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

when i deploy my code to the aws serverless then its error comes in my windows 10 but my friends computer is perfectly fine
i am new in aws serverlesss please help me

Error -

```
Error: Profile gifted does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably your friend uses `gifted` [AWS credentials profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html). If you want to keep using the same profile name, you can create the `gifted` credentials profile as shown in the linked docs.

Or use your own profile `serverless deploy --aws-profile <profile name>` as shown [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/configure-multiple-aws-profiles.html).